# How to select the first item of a combo box in an Access Web-compatible form?

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access, sharepoint-2010, ms-access-2010

I've created an Access Web database on SharePoint 2010 and I'm editing its forms with Access 2010.

One form includes a set of cascading combo boxes that I've created following these tutorials
[Combo Box in Access](http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Combo_Box) and [Cascading Combo Boxes](http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Cascading_Combo_Boxes). The actual data binding is working as expected.

The issue is that when the cascaded combo boxes receive their bound values, the selected item is left blank and I'd like it to pick the first element by default i.e. combo.items(0)

I understand that I'll have to add some sort of macro to select the first element. However, I haven't found a way to do so.

Currently the primary combo boxes invoke through an `after update` event a `requery` action on the cascaded combos.

Is there another action that could force as well the selection of the first bound item?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=38754

You can do this trick OnLoad. So your VBA code behind the form will look something like:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Me.cboTestCombo = Me.cboTestCombo.Column(0, 0)

End Sub
```

You may need to play around with the indices on Column(N, N) - the example above worked for me to place the first entry from my data rowsource in the combo at start.